# Recovery data from a double (accidentally) formatted HDD HFS+

Tags: macos, data-recovery, hfs+

Could be possible **recovery** original HDD data from a **double formatted** HDD?
I have erroneous repeated the formatting on a working disk twice, could be possible recovery original one table allocation files?
Used apple osx, formatted file system HFS+.
I never tried with foremost.. I recovered most data using RecoverIt but more data are damaged.

HDD it was no longer used. No data written since I'm still trying to recover more data (video GoPro/Mavic DJI video).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Likely not possible except with the aid of a recovery agency.  It will depend in part on how you formatted it (Full or Quick).

Comment: Quick format, twice.. Foremost (I don't know) could help?

Comment: Likely, a few files might be recoverable.... However, if the files are of great value to you, **stop using the drive and take it to a professional recovery service**. If the goal is to try to recover some "low hanging fruit," and then give up, you can try various other tools. You might make a clone of the disk, and try recovery on the clone, because some tools will cause further damage.

Comment: It is unlikely you could recover the original table allocation files.

Comment: Since the drive is undamaged, the only danger is overwriting, so just don't write anything and you're fine, although a cloned working copy would be safest (`gddrescue`). Testdisk and it's companion Photorec are terminal programs with "terminal-gui's", with menus and options to highlight with the arrows and enter/space. Testdisk can search for deleted partitions, and sometimes list original directory trees and files for copying with their original filenames. Photorec is a data carver that searches every sector looking for what appears to be files, with no original filenames. Try testdisk first

Comment: Thanks @Xen2050 but TestDisk work fine even twice formatted? I never used again this drive.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik drive isn't used.

Comment: gddrescue or ddrescue are the same?

Comment: @Larsenio, if you are trying to recover files from it, *it is being used*. Make a clone, and recover from that.

Comment: Testdisk may or may not work, it's worth a try imo. It shouldn't write any changes unless you explicitly say to write. Actually,  just not writing to a drive can be tricky, windows might ask (insistently) to format and auto-mount everything. Even linux's _read-only_ `mount -vo ro` could do some journal related writes. I'm not sure about MacOS

Comment: Regardless, having a clone copy on another HD to work/play with would be safest. GNU ddrescue (manual https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html ) is a great clone/recovery tool, but since your drive is still functioning physically ok it's probably overkill in this case, Mac's [Disk Utility](https://superuser.com/questions/62406/how-to-copy-a-partition-in-osx) should be enough (but ddrescue is still good to review for when it's really needed. I think homebrew for mac has it, from a basic web search.)

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik isnt used/writed drive, its external fw HDD..

Comment: @Xen2050 its external firewire drive, Mac OS extended (journaled) formatted twice so.. most of the time turned off cause I always hope to be able to recover the formatted partition entirely (but as I said, I accidentally formatted it 2 times in a row).. in 4 years of data recovery tests on it, on 2 TB of disk, I recovered 12 TB of data in many others HDD, some very old and useless... Im tring also DMDE. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what a mac **quick format** does. On linux _I think_ a plain format with say `mke2fs` would write the structures for the new FS, leaving everything else. I know `gparted` does a `wifefs` (erases FS "signatures" but not the FS itself) before any formats. So even if TestDisk can't find / list any files, there should be a lot of raw data for PhotoRec - only unsorted and unnamed. Using a `find -iname "*.jpg" ... | xargs mv ...` type script for sorting might help, and maybe tell PhotoRec to not recover a lot of "useless" files, or just `find ... | xargs rm` them

Comment: @Xen2050 I recovered double amount of data from this drive, but many DNG or h265 codec video are damaged.. so I would like to try if there was another way. JPEG's photo are intact, but many .dng (DJI photo) or MP4 h265 are damaged..  thanks a lot.

Comment: That's good and bad news... _I think_ some corrupted data is common for carvers like photorec & foremost, especially if the filesystem has fragmented a file the carver probably wouldn't know where the remaining file pieces are, or how to differentiate them from other file fragments. I'm not familiar with commercial data recovery programs, but iirc some advertise a "free sample" mode, maybe you could try a couple and have them only look for .dng & h265 .mp4's, to see if any better/fuller files are recovered, before paying?

Comment: Contacting a commercial data recovery firm is always an option. Since the drive still reads 100% ok and you have made a full `dd` / `gddrescue` image, you _might_ be able to send them the image over the internet, saving shipping costs & time (if it's possible/easier/faster), and let them know the only file types you're looking for. Some _might possibly_ also have a "pay for only what we recover" policy, but make sure you find out for sure before having any work done, so both you and them will be satisfied with whatever they find & charge.